Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: An equivalent constraint already exists, 'Constraint( id=4, name='constraint_b7299877', type='
this is the error
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: An equivalent constraint already exists, 'Constraint( id=4, name='constraint_b7299877', type='NODE PROPERTY EXISTENCE', schema=(:profile {userName}) )'.
public static void InitProfileDb() {
    String queryStr;

    try (Session session = ProfileMicroserviceApplication.driver.session()) {
      try (Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction()) {
        queryStr = "CREATE CONSTRAINT FOR (nProfile:profile) REQUIRE nProfile.userName IS NOT NULL";
        trans.run(queryStr);

        queryStr = "CREATE CONSTRAINT FOR (nProfile:profile) REQUIRE nProfile.password IS NOT NULL";
        trans.run(queryStr);

//        queryStr = "CREATE CONSTRAINT FOR (nProfile:profile) REQUIRE nProfile.userName IS UNIQUE";
//        trans.run(queryStr);

        trans.commit();
      }
      session.close();
    }
  }


The exception means what it says: the constraint already exists, you can't have more than one of the same kind of constraint on the same label / property combination.
You may want to consider using the IF NOT EXISTS flag in your constraint creation queries, that will allow them to be no-op, and avoid the exception, if the constraint is already there.
For review, here's our constraint documentation that includes usage of the flag:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/5/constraints/syntax/#constraints-syntax-create
